# Android MySql password verification not working

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am developing an android application in which the user will save the username and password to the database and the values are saved in the database. When the user comes next time he can sign-in instead of signup, so at that time, the user entered username and password is checked with the data saved in the table, If username matches with the password, User will be directed to the next page else an error message will be shown. In my case the signup process is working fine and in Sign-in process. when executing the process is not working. I am adding my activity and php file used to connect the database with app and the logcat. Please check this and if any error pls help me to solve it. Thanks.

Activity

```
public class SignInActivity extends Activity 


{
    /*LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;*/
    Button btnsignin;
    String name,password, psw;


    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();



    // single product url
    private static final String url_get_name = "http://iascpl.com/app/get_name_details.php";


    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String TAG_PASSWORD = "password";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signin_xm);


        /*loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();*/

        btnsignin = (Button) findViewById ( R.id.button401);



        btnsignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 

        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                new GetNameDetails().execute();

            }
        });
    }


        class GetNameDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignInActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading the result... Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * Getting product details in background thread
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) 


            {

                final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText401);
                final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText402);




                name =et1.getText().toString();
                password = et2.getText().toString();




                            // Building Parameters
                            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));




                            // getting product details by making HTTP request
                            // Note that product details url will use GET request
                            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                    url_get_name, "GET", params);



                            // check your log for json response
                            Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());


                            // json success tag

                            try {
                            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                            if (success == 1) {
                                // successfully received product details
                                JSONArray productObj = json
                                        .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                                // get first product object from JSON Array
                                final JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                                // product with this pid found
                                // Edit Text




                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() 
                                    {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        try {

                                            psw = product.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);
                                            if (password == psw);
                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                                                Intent i = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,HomePageActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(i);
                                            }





                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }else{
                                // product with pid not found
                            }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }




                    return null;
                }
/**
                             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                             * **/
                            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
                            {
                                // dismiss the dialog once got all details
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                            }



            }
    }
```

PHP

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will get single product details
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */ 
// array for JSON response



$response = array();




// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';



// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();




// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["name"])) {
    $name = $_GET['name'];

    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM numerol WHERE name = $name");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $product = array();
            $product["name"] = $result["name"];
            $product["passwordr"] = $result["password"];
           // $product["price"] = $result["price"];
            //$product["description"] = $result["description"];
            $product["created_at"] = $result["created_at"];
            $product["updated_at"] = $result["updated_at"];


            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["product"] = array();

            array_push($response["product"], $product);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

logcat

```
11-09 09:18:01.930: E/Trace(5068): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-09 09:18:04.410: D/gralloc_goldfish(5068): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-09 09:18:09.303: D/dalvikvm(5068): GC_CONCURRENT freed 83K, 7% free 2712K/2916K, paused 74ms+98ms, total 704ms
11-09 09:18:11.200: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:20.180: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:23.910: D/dalvikvm(5068): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 6% free 2872K/3048K, paused 61ms, total 82ms
11-09 09:18:23.931: I/dalvikvm-heap(5068): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.526MB for 635812-byte allocation
11-09 09:18:24.101: D/dalvikvm(5068): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 3490K/3672K, paused 165ms, total 165ms
11-09 09:18:24.341: D/dalvikvm(5068): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 5% free 3501K/3672K, paused 32ms+95ms, total 242ms
11-09 09:18:24.841: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:25.690: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:26.030: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:26.860: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:28.152: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:29.102: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:30.110: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:30.522: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:31.310: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:33.371: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:33.580: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:37.130: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:37.562: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:39.361: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:39.500: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:41.312: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:44.911: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:45.660: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:47.970: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:50.081: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:51.350: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:18:51.720: D/Single Product Details(5068): {"message":"No product found","success":0}
11-09 09:19:12.970: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:13.170: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:18.532: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:18.740: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:24.440: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:24.630: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:25.001: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:25.610: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 146 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:26.520: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:27.412: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:28.701: D/Single Product Details(5068): {"message":"No product found","success":0}
11-09 09:19:51.432: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:53.631: D/dalvikvm(5068): GC_CONCURRENT freed 166K, 8% free 3740K/4028K, paused 74ms+101ms, total 332ms
11-09 09:19:54.360: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 112 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:54.560: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:55.591: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 195 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:55.921: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 80 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:56.150: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:56.562: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:56.831: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:56.955: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:57.471: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:57.662: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:58.100: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:58.350: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:59.010: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:19:59.661: D/Single Product Details(5068): {"message":"No product found","success":0}
11-09 09:20:46.300: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:23:11.740: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:25:55.341: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:26:51.270: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:27:01.220: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:28:31.342: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-09 09:29:01.193: I/Choreographer(5068): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: did u checked the php service by running on browser?

Comment: http://iascpl.com/app/get_name_details.php  This is the url and I am getting a message like success

Comment: what is valid username and password?

Comment: Is name a string column? VARCHAR? CHAR? If so, should you not be quoting your variable. Btw, you're also open to SQL injection here.

Comment: @WayneWhitty its VARCHAR

Comment: hey u need to use AsyncTask so ur app is Crashing

Comment: The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Answer (score 0):

The doInBackground() isn't suppose to handle the UI in the activity so showing toast while processing the doInBackground isnt a good idea. use onPostExecute() to deal with the UI 
EDITED!

```
 class GetNameDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignInActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading the result... Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) 


        {

            final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText401);
            final EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText402);




            name =et1.getText().toString();
            password = et2.getText().toString();


                       try { //edited

                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password)); //check this please.



                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_get_name, "GET", params);



                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());


                        // json success tag


                        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            final JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text

                            Intent i = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,HomePageActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(i);
                            return "true"; // if the login was successful return true string to the onPostExecute(String) and there show the Toast.

                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }




                return null;
            }
                       /**
                         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                         * **/
                        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
                        {
                            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                            if (file_url == "true")
                              Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            else
                              Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Login unsuccessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }



        }
}
```

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: Please explain in your answer, where the original code was going wrong.

Comment: @ OSama .. How we will test the password is correct or not in this answe

Comment: if the success == 1 it will return a string == "true" then onPostExecute() it will check if the string == true then it will show the toast. while if it is wrong it will show "login unsuccessful" toast. I added some comments within the code check it out

Comment: sorry, i didnt clean the brackets after i removed the runOnUiThread method. try it again please and inform me

Comment: umm btw you have missed the Password List, you are only sending the name to the PHP script. and why you are using the JSONArray productObj?!